# For loop in django html depending on the index (repeat every 3 times)

Tags: html, django

I am working with a bootstrap template for a django app

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
       <div class="card-deck-wrapper">
              <div class="card-deck">

                   {% if posts %}
                   {% for post in posts %}

                     <div class="card d-block">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ post.image }}" height="200">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">{{ post.description }}</p>
                            <p class="card-text">
                              <small class="text-muted">{{ post.creation_date }}</small>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                     </div> <!-- end card-->
                     
                  {% endfor %}
                  {% endif %}

              </div> <!-- end card-deck-->
          </div> <!-- end card-deck-wrapper-->
     </div> <!-- end col-->
 </div><!-- end row -->
```

Mi main target is to repeat each "card" just 3 times, otherwise the templates looks awful, but have no idea how to iterate just 3 times, and at the 4th, 7th, 10th, and so on time, create a new "card-deck" to continue with post 4-5-6, then another "card-deck" for post 7-8-9 and so on

Thank you!

I have changed it a little bit at least to know how many "card-deck" should it have in the views

```
def blogPost(request):
posts = Post.objects.filter(state=True)

numberOfPosts = len(posts)
addOneDeck = 0
if (numberOfPosts%3) > 0:
    addOneDeck = 1

numberOfDecks = ((int(numberOfPosts/3))+addOneDeck)
    

context = {"posts":posts, "decks":numberOfDecks}

return render(request,"blog.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for forloop counter in templates? django has builtin for that

```
{% for post in posts %}
   {{ forloop.counter }} #The current iteration of the loop (1-indexed)
   {{ forloop.counter0 }} #The current iteration of the loop (0-indexed)

   {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %}
        <p>print {{ forloop.counter0 }}</p>
   {% else %}
        <p> do something else</p>
   {% endif %}

{% endfor % }}
```

you can use within if else conditions then.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Comment: yeah..that works...but how do i make it stop at 3? For example...I have 10 posts...so the forloop.counter has to stop at post #3, then the other loop has to start at 4....is there a way to do that on the template...or is it better to take it to the views?

Comment: put `<div class="card-deck">` inside the forloop. and then you can do this using logical operation.

Comment: I was trying to use this...but i guess the template can't understand this... {% if forloop.counter0 % 3 != 0 %}  .... the error i get is Could not parse the remainder: '%' from '%'

Comment: @AndresCamino Oops, my bad. You need to use filters for perform math operations in templates. it will be 

 `{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %}
`
You can find details about using tags and filters in templates in here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/